# How to improve performance of WPF application with multiple background workers

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have some WPF application which downloads files via `Background Worker` and at the same time shows some animations.

The main problem that in that moment animation gets stuck periodically.

I have no idea why. But I guess that I have to put down priority of that `Background Worker` which downloads files.

Any clue how is better merge animation and file downloading under WPF application?

Surely I can always devide this functionality but the idea is to keep all-in-one bottle. :)

Any good performance approaches?

Thank you folk!

Comment: Impossible to guess from the question, it isn't documented nearly well enough.  Comment out any ReportProgress calls and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: I think you need to move into full threading to get priority on background.   http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vblanguage/thread/34cf0b06-1cda-403f-99db-60a0a8f24875

Comment: @Blam Yes. I have 9  background workers and they uses the same network connection to RIA Services.

Comment: Then give the answer from Erno a try and post some code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that the 9 BackgroundWorkers are queuing up for the UI thread to report progress.

Solutions:

- less backgroundworkers - 9 is a lot of connections to the server, perhaps you could try to load more data in one call.
- less progress reporting - If the UI thread is the bottleneck you could have the backgroundworkers each set a property and have one backgroundworker report all the progress.
- less animations - will free the UI thread too.